# Any good replacements for Microsoft Money that will work well for the U.K.?

Tags: united-kingdom, microsoft-money, software, alternatives

I use MS-Money to track my account and investments, as Microsoft is just about to kill MS-Money, what are the good replacements?

I need a product that can cope with the fact I live in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

Since Quicken was withdrawn from the UK market, I've made do with an OpenOffice spreadsheet and a bit of ninja function/formatting.

***Note:***As pointed out by Chris in the comments, it looks like this product is aimed at small businesses rather than personal use.

I did a little look around though and found that [QuickBooks](http://quickbooks.intuit.co.uk/accounting-software/products/quickbooks-pro-demo.jsp) is available in a UK version. There are a few little video demos on the linked page, and you can buy [various versions at Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s?ie=UTF8&ref%5F=nb%5Fss%5Fsw%5Fh%5F&field-keywords=quickbooks&url=search-alias%3Dsoftware) starting from around £55 for the "SimpleStart 2008" version.

I'm afraid I have no direct experience with this product so can't recommend it or warn you off it.

Comment: I think QuickBooks is an accounting package for small business, not really designed/intended for personal finance management.

Comment: Chris I think you may be right